# how can force a generic class use T constructor with parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Generic class like this :

```
public class Mapper<TEntity, TDataAccess>
    where TEntity : Common.IEntity
    where TDataAccess : DataAccess, new()
{
    public TDataAccess DataAccess { get; set; } 
    public Mapper()
    {
        DataAccess = new TDataAccess();
    }
    /*
     * ...
     * */
}
```

and data access is like this :

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public DataAccess()
    {}

    public DataAccess(string tranName)
    {}

    // CRUD functionality and other data access staff
}
```

and a inherited class form `DataAccess` :

```
public class UserDataAccess:DataAccess
{
    public UserDataAccess():base(string.Empty)
    {
    }
    public UserDataAccess(string tranName):base(tranName)
    {
        // Something to do with user
    }
}
```

and finally `UserMapper` from Mapper :

```
public class UserMapper : Mapper<User,UserDataAccess>
{
    // Mapping entity properties with datarows columns
}
```

now imagine that I need to send `tranName` to given `TDataAccess` in `UserMapper`. how can do this without changing `DataAccess` class ? I can't access the source of `DataAccess` and also Generics don't realize Types different constructor overloads.
I know that I can have a property on `UserDataAccess` and fill it whenever I need, but I can't because of thread safety issue.

The `User` class is a plain entity - it has only properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics does not support that. Options:

- have a `protected virtual TDataAccess CreateDataAccess()` method, that **by default** uses `new TDataAccess()`, but which can be overridden by `UserMapper` to create the object any way it likes; call `CreateDataAccess()` instead of `new TDataAccess()`
- pass in a factory method as a delegate, i.e. a `Func<TDataAccess>` - so the caller could supply `() => new DataAccess("foo")`, and use that instead of the `new TDataAccess()`
- use reflection-based code to create the `TDataAccess` - either `Activator.CreateInstance` (which supports parameters), or something involving meta-programming (`Expression`, `ILGenerator`, etc)

Answer (score 3):

As a case you can use overload of the [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) method by specifying constructor parameter:

```
var dataAccess = Activator.CreateInstance(
                            typeof(TDataAccess), 
                            new object[] { tranName });
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx):

```
public static Object CreateInstance(
    Type type,
    params Object[] args
)
```

> Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that
>   best matches the specified parameters.